# QML Sceneloader and LayerFilter

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

How can I add my object loaded with a `SceneLoader` to a layer?

In my QML project, I'm applying a layer filter, and showing certain things on some layers, others on other layers, etc...

I can add a mesh to a layer with:

```
 Mesh {
    id: barrel
    source: "qrc:/assets/metalbarrel/metal_barrel.obj"
 }
 Q3D.Entity {
    id: barrelEntity
    components: [ solidLayer, barrel, barrelTransform]
 }
```

But I can't figure out how to do the same with something loaded with `SceneLoader`, which I need because I want to use a 3ds (transformed with `qgtfl`) object.

e.g.

```
 SceneLoader {
    id: ship
    source: "qrc:/models/Ship_meteor_N010311.qgltf"
 }
 Q3D.Entity {
    id: barrelEntity
    components: [ solidLayer, ship ]
 }
```

won't work, nor has any other permutation that I've tried so far. (Defining it in the layer, defining it in the `LayerFilter`, wrapping it with an entity, putting the `SceneLoader` in the entity with the components, etc)